# c# uwp winrt Image or Bitmap Image to base64

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Video.png"));

I am trying to convert a bitmap image to base64 to string on universal app.Do have any idea about how it can be ?

Comment: What is the reason you do not respond or vote/ mark answers people give to your answers? People put work in to help, the least we can do is to give people reputation as reward.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your image to bytes. Then you can call [Convert.ToBase64String.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Convert.ToBase64String);k(ToBase64String);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

There's couple good sources of information for this:

[Reading and Writing Base64 in the Windows Runtime](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html)

[Codepaste](http://codepaste.net/ijx28i)

To summarize these, to **convert Image to base64**, you should be able to use the following method:

```
        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await bitmap.RenderAsync(ImageControl);

        var image = (await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync()).ToArray();
        var width = (uint) bitmap.PixelWidth;
        var height = (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight;

        double dpiX = 96;
        double dpiY = 96;

        var encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, encoded);

        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, width, height, dpiX, dpiY, image);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        encoded.Seek(0);

        var bytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
        await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```